# Magento2: REST API : Save Product Detail per store view not working

Tags: api, rest, product, magento2

Using Magento2.1.0-rc1 Branch 
With Sample Data

Using REST API catalogProductRepositoryV1 REF: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html
Get Key from Admin token API 
and use that key in

> POST /V1/products

&

> PUT /V1/products/{sku}

with parameter tried with both parameter one by one

- store_id=0
- storeId=0 
  using following JSON

```html
{
    "saveOptions": "true",
    "product": {
        "name": "Test11_11",
        "sku": "TESTOPP_111",
        "attributeSetId": "15",
        "price": "10",
        "weight": "10",
        "status": "1",
        "visibility": "3",
        "customAttributes": [
            {
                "attributeCode": "manufacturer",
                "value": "222"
            },
            {
                "attributeCode": "tax_class_id",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "attributeCode": "specialPrice",
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
                "attributeCode": "description",
                "value": "44332211"
            },
            {
                "attributeCode": "eco_collection",
                "value": "1"
            }
        ],
        "typeId": "simple"
    }
}
```

Does not support store_id / storeId field , 
but the information in product does not save to store 
it save to default Store ID

**GET /V1/products** has parameter storeId 
same i had tried with PUT & POST but not working with PUT & POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after debugging a lot on Magento2, Found that Magento2 does not have any functionality to Store Data from REST API as per StoreID 
**getStore** function in **StoreManager** just check if store is exist in session else return default , that is why all **REST** API Calls are stored in default store ID

I have Over Rided **Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager** as below :

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager" type="Emizentech\MobileAdmin\Model\EmizenStoreManager" />
</config>
```

> vim Model/EmizenStoreManager.php

```
<?php
namespace Emizentech\MobileAdmin\Model;

use Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class EmizenStoreManager extends \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager
{
        /**
     * Request instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $_request;

         /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
     * @param \Magento\Store\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
     * @param \Magento\Store\Api\WebsiteRepositoryInterface $websiteRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param StoreResolverInterface $storeResolver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $cache
     * @param bool $isSingleStoreAllowed
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Api\WebsiteRepositoryInterface $websiteRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreResolverInterface $storeResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $cache,
        RequestInterface $request,
        $isSingleStoreAllowed = true
    ) {
        $this->storeRepository = $storeRepository;
        $this->websiteRepository = $websiteRepository;
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeResolver = $storeResolver;
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->isSingleStoreAllowed = $isSingleStoreAllowed;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getStore($storeId = null)
    {

                if($this->_request->isPut() && strlen($this->_request->getParam('storeId')))
                {
                        return parent::getStore($this->_request->getParam('storeId'));
                }
                return parent::getStore($storeId);
    }

}
```

in this file i have check that if Request type is **PUT** 
and URL Paramater **storeId** exist than Set that Store else call **parent::getStore()**

and in **REST** API **PUT** Call, I have added **storeId** in all request in which I need to set information to be stored as per StoreID & it works like a charm :) 
for store values in admin i am using **storeID=0** ByDefault for all PUT Requests.

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered a similar scenario where I want to update prices per website. So to update the price, I've used

```
/rest/<store_code>/V1/products/<sku>
```

This worked fine.

So I assume you can use this to update product data per store.

Answer (score 7):

`/rest/<store_code>/V1/products/<sku>`

This one works, you can use

- all
- default

for store codes

Comment: Thanks for this answer. There is an issue  (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4952) reported for this, but this seems to help. To improve your question: 'all' equals store_id=0 (admin), but `default` can be variable. True, in a fresh installation it's default, but in multistore this can be 'en', 'de', 'fr', etc.