# Magento 2 - REST API PUT product

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

When I try to update a product, created via the REST V1 API, only the values are updated for de default website. Unfortunattely I can't find any possibility to send website id's within te json. Does anyone have experienced this before?

The data I send for the update to /V1/products/123456:

```
{"product":{"sku":"123456","name":"D4D0123299","price":21,"type_id":"simple","custom_attributes":[],"extension_attributes":{"stock_item":{"use_config_manage_stock":1}}}}"
```

Linking the product to specific websites is done with a second request, after creating it via /V1/products, to /V1/products/123456/websites (POST) with this data foreach website:

```
"{"productWebsiteLink":{"sku":"D4D01232","websiteId":1}}"
"{"productWebsiteLink":{"sku":"D4D01232","websiteId":2}}"
```

The **Magento 2** version is **2.1.0**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento2 always set default store while PUT or POST API Calls

to save values with ref to Store you can use like following

API URL

```
http://yourmagento2store.com/rest/default/V1/products/123456
```

where **default** is the store code

you can also use **admin** if you want to update @ Admin level not store level.

```
http://yourmagento2store.com/rest/admin/V1/products/123456
```

if you need any custom than you can also refer to [Magento2: REST API : Save Product Detail per store view not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744874/magento2-rest-api-save-product-detail-per-store-view-not-working/37875681#37875681)

Comment: Is there a way to change for example the productname for alle stores in one PUT request? Or a way to update the whole product for all stores in one PUT request?

Comment: When I do the request to http://yourmagento2store.com/rest/admin/V1/products/123456 I get the following response:
Client error: `PUT http://yourmagento2store.com/rest/admin/V1/products/123456` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{"message":"Request does not match any route."}
It didn't work the way you suggested. Are you sure this should work for Magento 2? I also couldn't find any documentation about this.

Comment: Same for  yourmagento2store.com/rest/0/V1/products/123456 by the way

Comment: 0 is admin store id : use "admin" as :  yourmagento2store.com/rest/admin/V1/products/123456

Comment: also if this is not working you can try with this solution mentioned in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744874/magento2-rest-api-save-product-detail-per-store-view-not-working/37875681#37875681 
and use store id in URL Parameter

Comment: How to get the custom attributes ids in an the products' api response. I am getting only two parameters `"attribute_code": "options_container", "value": "container2"`. My API call is https://mydomain/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1